# Generate a partially shaded runnable jar with Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a deploy environment where I have the following directory structure:

```
+--runnable.jar
+--thirdparty_lib
   +-- a.jar
   +-- b.jar
   +-- c.jar
```

This works out well because we have fairly frequent deploys, but infrequent thirdparty_lib updates (of which there are a large number, taking a long period of time). [going forward, this structure and deployment system is not tenable, but it's what we have for now, and don't want to change it]

Code in runnable.jar is generated from eclipse from multiple projects (including some shared internal libraries).

I have created a Maven module for each of our projects in order to manage internal and third party dependencies. I created an initial build configuration (using maven-jar-plugin and maven-dependency-plugin) that generates

```
+--runnable.jar
+--lib
   +-- a.jar
   +-- b.jar
   +-- c.jar
   +-- internaldependency1.jar
   +-- internaldependency2.jar
```

This runs fine, *but* it means updating all the internaldependencies on deploy.

So I would like to include some .jar files in runnable.jar, for rapid deployment, and the others in the thirdparty_lib folder, which won't need deploying so often.

I've run into several problems and have a tentative solution, outlined as an answer below, but it seems overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

My solution needs three parts

- use maven-shade-plugin to include internal dependency jars in the runnable.jar
- use maven-dependency-plugin copy-dependencies to copy other dependencies
- set the correct classpath in runnable.jar's manifest

First two parts are quite easy. The configuration for maven-shade-plugin needs

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <artifactSet>
    <includes>
      <include>INTERNAL_GROUP</include>
    </includes>
  </artifactSet>
</configuration>
```

The configuration for maven-dependency-plugin:copy-dependencies

```
<configuration>
  <outputDirectory>thirdparty_lib</outputDirectory>
  <excludeGroupIds>INTERNAL_GROUP</excludeGroupIds>
</configuration>
```

But setting the classpath proved challenging. Wildcards are not allowed in runnable jar manifests. Neither are bare folder names. Previously, the maven-jar-plugin generated the classpath from the dependencies, but now...?

I found that maven-dependency-plugin:build-classpath did a good job of creating the classpath I wanted, but took a pathSeparator which could not be an empty string (all variants I tried removed the whitespace when generating the Effective POM). I could then output this to a runtime property (except with the wrong separator for a jar manifest, which needs spaces between paths).

```
<configuration>
  <prefix>thirdparty_lib</prefix>
  <pathSeparator>:</pathSeparator>
  <outputProperty>CLASSPATH_WITH_WRONG_SEPARATOR</outputProperty>
  <excludeGroupIds>INTERNAL_GROUP </excludeGroupIds>
</configuration>
```

I solved this rather inelegantly using gmaven-plugin

```
<configuration>
  <source>
    project.properties.setProperty(
      'CLASSPATH_WITH_SPACES',
      project.properties.CLASSPATH_WITH_WRONG_SEPARATOR.replace(':', ' ')
    )
  </source>
</configuration>
```

And adding the following entries to the maven-shade-plugin configuration

```
<transformers>
  <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
   <manifestEntries>
    <Main-Class>MAIN</Main-Class>
    <Class-Path>${CLASSPATH_WITH_SPACES}</Class-Path>
   </manifestEntries>
  </transformer>
</transformers>
```